# Fetch between two characters

Tags: php, regex, notepad++

I have an CSV like this:

```
43132,000.121.211.254,,NO DATA,office@mail.com,VIEW,2012-11-28 13:17:31
43126,000.123.54.1,,NO DATA,mat.plast@mail.com,VIEW,2012-11-28 13:04:45
43121,000.24.74.155,,NO DATA,sales@mail.mail,VIEW,2012-11-28 12:58:38
43118,000.115.243.218,,NO DATA,guta@mail.com,VIEW,2012-11-28 12:55:59
43116,80006.124.167.204,,NO DATA,mogosanu@mail.ro,VIEW,2012-11-28 12:54:11
```

and what i want to do is to replace with notepad++ `office` , `mat.plast` , `sales` , `guta` , `mogosanu` with `PRIVATEMAIL` therefore i need an regex expresion.

How do i match everything between `,` and `@` so i can replace it

my idea was something like

`#\,(.*)\@#`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you're doing this in notepad++, what's the [tag:php] tag for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Find what: (?<=,)[^,@]+(?=@)
Replace with: PRIVATEMAIL
```

How does this work? `(?<=,)` asserts that the match starts to the right of a comma. `[^,@]+` matches any non-comma, non-at characters (as many as possible). `(?=@)` asserts that there is an `@` to the right of the match. Note that neither the lookbehind, nor the lookahead are included in the actual match, which is why they are not removed.

Note that the lookbehind could be left out, because the regex engine tries to match from left to right.

You could do the same without lookarounds, but then you have to write back the delimiters:

```
Find what: ,[^,@]+@
Replace with: ,PRIVATEMAIL@
```

(Again you could leave out the leading comma from both strings.)

And here is why your pattern doesn't work. Firstly, Notepad++ doesn't use delimiters for regular expressions, so there is no need for the surrounding `#` (instead they would be treated as literal characters to be matched). Secondly `.*` matches any character (except line breaks, unless you select that option). That includes commas and at signs. So the `,` would match the first comma in the string. Then `.*` would gladly consume everything until the `@` (including all the values in between). That's why we need to exclude the `,` from the repeated characters, using a negated character class.

Comment: Yes this is a good approach. Also you explain a good part of regular expressions in greater depth.

Comment: first of all, `(?<=,)[^,@]+(?=@)` won't work, second i don't understand `[^,@]` i mean i understood that the regex tells me "Find between `,`  and `@` but what does it means `[^,@]`, find all characters except `,` and `@`, am i right?

Comment: @HashGuy if the first one doesn't work, make sure you have upgraded to Notepad++ 6. Before that there were a lot of issues with the regex engine. `[^,@]` matches a single character that is neither a comma nor an at. That's important to get the shortest possible string between a comma and an at (instead of consuming other commas and ats with something like `.`).

Answer (score 0):

`/,([A-Za-z]+)\@/` seems to match what you'd like fine, HashGuy.

Comment: this is it wokring as well, but like this `Find What : ,([A-Za-z]+)\@` witch means that this will search between `,` and `@` for `[A-Za-z]` no matter how many are they, but at least one (`+`), and `,` + `@` must be escaped, right?

Comment: That was tested with one of your sample lines. 

Escaping is only required if you the character's special meaning to not be ignored and matched literally. The ',' needn't be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

```
Find what: ,[^\@,]+\@([^\.]+\.[^,]+),
Replace with: ,PRIVATEMAIL@\1,
```

This would not change something that contains @, but it is not like an email.

Comment: this is a different approach then `m.buettner` , so basically this means that Notepad++ will search everything between `,` and `,` only if inside of that between contains something with `@`, righr?

Comment: Yes, it will search for ,<somethingelsethan@>@<somethingelsethan.>.somechars,
Currently, now TLDs are not restricted to predefined like .com, .net, you could buy whatever you like, in theory ($200k/year is custom TLD) so.